# Passing nested dictionary as extra_vars to ansible-playbooks

Tags: ansible, python-3.5, ansible-2.x, ansible-runner

I want to pass a huge nested dictionary as an `extra_vars` to an Ansible `playbook`. I want to use values from that dictionary in my playbook.

```py
sample_dict = { 'student' : {'name' : 'coder', 'marks' : 100} }
```

I want to pass this dictionary as an `extra_var` I want to use the values from it. I am not able to access separate values from the dictionary using `jinja` templating.

Example:
If I want to use the value of marks in an `ansible-playbook`, how do I access it?

I am using `python3.5` and `ansible 2.8.` I am using `ansible-runner` module to run the playbooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can walk dictionaries in `jinja` in two ways:

1. Using the python interface.
2. Using the `json_query` filter

The first one uses brackets `[]` to travel through the dictionary. And, `json_query` takes in a string with the path to key you want to read.

Check this `playbook` example:

```
---
- name: Diff test
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    sample_dict:
      student:
        name: 'coder'
        marks: 100
  tasks:
    - name: Using python dictionary interface
      debug:
        msg: '{{ sample_dict["student"]["marks"] }}'

    - name: Using json_query
      debug:
        msg: '{{ sample_dict | json_query("student.marks") }}'
```

Each task uses a different method to access the same variable.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But actual situation is that, I am passing the dictionary from my python program as extra_vars to the ansible-playbook. My dictionary is not declared in yaml itself.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you pass the dict. It works the same. If it isn't, then the problem is that what you think is a dictionary actually isn't. If you can't read it with this code then you need to check the type of your variable and confirm that it is a dictionary.